# How to use group by based on 2 columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server as below
[image]

I want to count distinct order_number for each country and group by Month and year as below 
[image]

I am using this query but i am not getting the result i want

```
select 
concat(DATENAME(month, purchase_date), '  ' , DATENAME(year, purchase_date)) as [Month-Year],
country, count(distinct [order_number]) as [Distinct Order Number]
from SC.mytable
group by DATENAME(year, purchase_date), DATENAME(month, purchase_date),country
Order by DATENAME(year, purchase_date) ASC,
case DATENAME(month, purchase_date) 
when 'January' then 1
when 'February' then 2
when 'March' then 3
when 'April' then 4
when 'May' then 5
when 'June' then 6
when 'July' then 7
when 'August' then 8
when 'September' then 9
when 'October' then 10
when 'November' then 11
when 'December' then 12
end asc
,country asc
```

I am getting the result as below

[image]

can you please advise what is wrong in the group by so that the Month-Year will be shown horizontal in the header ?

Here is the table creation and values in case you need to try it. Thank you for your support.

```
CREATE TABLE SC.mytable (
  country varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  order_number varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  order_item varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  purchase_date date NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO SC.mytable (country, order_number, order_item, purchase_date) VALUES
  ('Germany', '4311787830', '10','2018-11-01'),
  ('France', '4221669938', '90','2018-10-29'),
  ('Austria', '4216370706', '50','2018-08-17'),
  ('Austria', '4216370706', '60','2018-08-17'),
  ('Germany', '4320162822', '10','2018-07-16'),
  ('Germany', '4320162822', '20','2018-07-16'),
  ('UK', '4216775391', '80','2018-04-30'),
  ('UK', '4214370307', '50','2018-08-23'),
  ('Germany', '4311780287', '40','2018-03-11'),
  ('Germany', '4216334860', '70','2018-08-27'),
  ('Spain', '4911235852', '30','2018-12-10'),
  ('Spain', '4719832003', '90','2018-12-18'),
  ('France', '4216325304', '30','2018-05-04'),
  ('France', '4216325304', '40','2018-05-04');
```

Comment: `group by` itself will never give you columns... only rows. If you want to convert rows into columns please take a look at the `pivot` function.

Comment: Change those CASE WHEN DATENAME to a call to MONTH(purchasedate). Every single use of DATENAME in this query is superfluous in some way or another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below query, it will help you.

```
SELECT country,
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'January' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "JAN-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'February' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "FEB-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'March' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "MAR-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'April' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "APR-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'May' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "MAY-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'June' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "JUN-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'July' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "JUL-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'August' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "AUG-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'September' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "SEP-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'October' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "OCT-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'November' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "NOV-18",
 CASE WHEN DATENAME(month, purchase_date) = 'December' THEN count(distinct [order_number]) ELSE 0 END AS "DEV-18"
 FROM 
mytable
 GROUP BY country,purchase_date
```

Comment: Change those CASE WHEN DATENAME to a call to MONTH(purchasedate)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample with pivoting. It will not generate columns dynamically though, like BI tools do it for you. The only way to make it dynamic is to generate sql code with a procedure and then execute it as a string.

```
select P.* from (
select country, left(purchase_date,7) as mon, order_number  from SC.mytable) M
pivot (
  count(order_number) 
  for mon in ([2018-08], [2018-09], [2018-10], [2018-11])
 ) as P
```

Comment: Oof, that's a bit of a nasty way to turn a date into a yyyy-mm. Why not use FORMAT(), or a combination of MONTH() / YEAR() / DATEPART()?

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet. I used Pivot and got the the same result as the table you want:

```
 SELECT country,[1] as Jan, [2] as Feb, [3] as Mar, [4] as Apr,[5] as May, [6] as 
 Jun, [7] as jul , [8] as Aug, [9] as Sep,[10] as Oct, [11] as  Nov, [12] as Dec  
 FROM   (SELECT country,  datepart( mm,purchase_date )  as mnt FROM mytable) p  
 PIVOT  (count( mnt) FOR Mnt IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10], 
 [11], [12]))AS unpvt;
```

Also, you can use this link for more instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAplA.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script as well which is not efficient but it works:

```
select country , 
  (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
  month(purchase_date) = 1) as Jan,
  (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
  month(purchase_date) = 2) as Feb,
  (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
  month(purchase_date) = 3) as Mar,
  (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
  month(purchase_date) = 4) as Apr,
  (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
 month(purchase_date) = 5) as May,
  (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
 month(purchase_date) = 6) as Jun,
  (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
 month(purchase_date) = 7) as Jul,
  (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
 month(purchase_date) = 8) as Aug,
  (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
 month(purchase_date) = 9) as Sep,
  (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
 month(purchase_date) = 10) as Oct,
 (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
 month(purchase_date) = 11) as Nov,
 (select count(*) from mytable t2 where t2.country = t.country and 
 month(purchase_date) = 12) as Dec
   FROM mytable t
   GROUP BY country


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2F8u.jpg
```